# How to graph an ellipsoid with only the three radii

Tags: 3d, graphing, wolframalpha

While working on a project, using a magnetometer chip, I have run into a problem where I need to graph some data, consisting of three diameters (or d/2 = radii). Is there an easy way to do this with Wolfram Alpha, or another online, free tool?

In addition, when checking this out on Wolfram Alpha before coming here, there was no good results.

Here is the search link if you would like to see:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+an+ellipsoid+with+three+radii

Note: Since this is for a personal project, I am in no way not inclined to "cheat" if need be, and if there is a way to solve for the traditional cartesian equation (in the form x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2 = 1) that would be perfectly fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you have a 3D volume that can be constructed by computing the convex hull of three discs? (Like three lemon slices pierced on a satay stick?)

Comment: @RoyT. to give a more precise image, each of the radii that I have is on a different plane, one parallel with the x axis, one parellel with the y axis, and one parallel to the z axis. It would look something like this: http://www.mhhe.com/math/calc/smithminton2e/cd/folder_structure/text/chap10/section06/figure_1056b.gif